# Filepath in war

Tags: java, xml, servlets, weblogic

I created sigleton `ApplicationConfig` for settigs, that reads xml config file. But every time it fails on path to file.

hierarchy:

```
META-INF
src
--application
----config.xml
--engine
----ApplicationConfig
web
--WEB-INF
----web.xml
```

I've tried `File f = new File("../application/config.xml");` but it gives `C:\WebLogic\application\config.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a bad idea to store your configs in 'src'. It's better to separate your code and configuration. I suggest you to read about maven (or gradle).
Basic maven app has pretty simple structure:

```
src    
--main
----java
----resources
```

where in 'java' folder you store your code, and in the 'resource' folder you store your configs. And now you have problem, because jvm is trying to find your file relatively WebLogic  base folder.

And if you use maven, you could just write:

```
ApplicationConfig.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.xml")
```

Of course, in this case you should put your config into 'resources' folder.